# Responding with Custom Errors Messages on Model Properties with Enum type using Attributes

Tags: c#, json, enums

API request Body JSON is parsed to Model. In Model I have multiple Enum Type properties. I want to return custom error message in case Enum parsing failed.

```
public Enums.YesNo Indicator { get; set; }
```

I am using `options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());` in Program.cs.

I would like to respond with 'Invalid Indicator value' error message if Yes/No is not provided in the JSON.

Tried using custom attribute validation:  `[StringEnumValidation(typeof(Enums.YesNo), "Invalid Indicator value.")]` and `[EnumDataType(typeof(Enums.YesNo), ErrorMessage = "Invalid Indicator value.")]`

Answer (score 0):

A ValidationAttribute that takes an Enum type and an error message can be defined.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebAppTestController;

public class EnumValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
  private Type _enumType;

  public EnumValidationAttribute(Type enumType, string errorMessage) : base(errorMessage)
  {
    _enumType = enumType;
  }

  protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
  {
    if (value == null || !Enum.IsDefined(_enumType, value))
    {
      return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
    }

    return ValidationResult.Success;
  }
}
```

It should be assigned to the property within your model. Example;

```
public class YourModel
{
    [EnumValidation(typeof(Enums.YesNo), "Invalid Indicator value.")]
    public Enums.YesNo Indicator { get; set; }
}
```

In case of an invalid condition, it will directly return 400, but if it doesn't occur, it can be used as follows. It will be used within a method in this controller.

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
  var errorMessages = ModelState.Values
      .SelectMany(v => v.Errors)
      .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage)
      .ToList();

  return BadRequest(new { Errors = errorMessages });
}
```

If you write the following in the program.cs, it will enter the method.

```
builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
  options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
});
```

***If SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter is true, the output is 'Watch'***

[image]

***If SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter is false, the response***

[image]

Comment: I am not getting the Error Message that I provided on the Attribute. I am getting "The JSON value could not be converted to Enums.YesNo. Path: $.Indicator | LineNumber: 108 | BytePositionInLine: 48."

Comment: The Breakpoint in IsValid method is not being hit. The error is thrown even before Attribute validations kick-off. No luck trying to Turn the Schema Binding validations off.                                               
builder.Services.AddControllers(
    options => options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true
    )

Comment: Would you mind specifying the .NET version of your project? Additionally, could you include a sample code snippet used in the controller within the context of the issue mentioned above?

Comment: .Net Version 8.
        [HttpPost, Route("report")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Submitreport([FromBody]Requests.Report)
        {
        }

Comment: I added the "SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter" code to the answer.

Comment: I have that statement in the Program.cs already. It didnt help.

Comment: @DRG I can't think of a different scenario. Nevertheless, I've included screen outputs for both cases where SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter is false and true in the response.